# Battery Full Charge Notification in Swift

Tags: swift

I am working on an app which needs to notify users when battery fully charged from Inactive State.Following code works ok only within the app.I am getting an UIAlertView when i open the app and notification fired when the app goes to foreground or background mode.but not much happening when app is in inactive State.can someone help me what missing in the following code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var localNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification!

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound |
        UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))


    if (localNotification != nil){
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    var state: UIApplicationState = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState
    if state == UIApplicationState.Active
    {

        var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Fully charged", message: notification.alertBody, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }
     application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}


func ViewDidLoad() {
    UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "notifyFullyCharged:", name: UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "notifyFullyCharged:", name: UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

}



func notifyFullyCharged() {
    UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    var batterylevel: Float = UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel==1.0 && UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState==UIDeviceBatteryState.Charging {
        var localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = nil
        localNotification.alertBody = "Unplug your device. Your battery has been fully charged."
        localNotification.alertAction = "Touch to view"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }
```

}

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game

    notifyFullyCharged()
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

}
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    notifyFullyCharged()
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

    notifyFullyCharged()
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    notifyFullyCharged()
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.


}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Apple docs? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification

Comment: Also, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification